# Updating more than one item in a RESTful way

Tags: rest

What should be the correct RESTful approach when trying to update/delete more than one item?

Typical example: There is a list of items, the income folder of mails received, where you can select a group of them by setting the appropiate checkboxes. Then you click in the "delete" button and send the petition of delete them. What method should I call? What parameters?

In this case it's pretty obvious I should use a `DELETE`, but it only works with one item at once. Also, I might not want to delete them, but storing them in a different folder, which might imply using a `PATCH`, but then again, the `PATCH` method only allows one item.

Comment: *the PATH method* you mean PATCH? Also, who says these methods only allow one item at a time?

Comment: In our project we have two approaches to this: 1st: send n `DELETE` (to delete) or n `PUT` (to move) requests to be (kind of) rest-conform. 2nd: Discuss in team if this use-case is suitable for a "custom action" what we call it. These custom actions are "misused" `POST` requests. For example: `POST users/move/{groupid}` that accepts a list of user-IDs as body and moves all of them to the desired group.

The criteria for what solution to use is basically the question "How often is this functionality used?" - if it's not a core function we choose 1st, if it's often used we choose 2nd.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Isn't PATH only allowed for one item at a time? This is where I got the idea: http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/patch/ . If you have other document resources, please let me know

Comment: No, depends on how the server is implemented, if it can process multiple resources in 1 request, then you can use that

Comment: @TimCastelijns Ok, so what would be the syntax?

Comment: I don't know, depends on how the server is implemented. I presume you didn't implement the server, so contact the guy who did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this case it's pretty obvious I should use a DELETE, but it only
>   works with one item at once. Also, I might not want to delete them,
>   but storing them in a different folder, which might imply using a
>   PATCH, but then again, the PATCH method only allows one item.

You should PATCH the collection (or a part of it) and not the item. For example by moving items, you could use `PATCH /collection/?filter=x {location: newDir}`. The DELETE is a tricky question. You can use the PATCH or an alternative to use the `DELETE /collection/?filter=x`, but that implies that you want to delete the collection resource instead of removing item resources from it. By batch creation I think using the `POST /collection/ [item1, item2, ...]` is okay.

Ofc. you can use alternative URI structues too, for example `PATCH /books/1+2+3/ {price: 20, currency: "EUR"}`. There is an alternative syntax for PATCH too, in that you add the operation name to the body, for example `PATCH /collection/?filter=x {op: "update", location: newDir}`. I don't like that, but if you want to reuse PATCH with the same URI, then it can become handy. Another alternative to send the request to a single batch endpoint e.g. `POST /transactions/` and use a multipart HTTP request.

I think the most important part here to keep in mind, what you are doing is forcing multiple operations into a single transaction. So if you don't need immediate consistency, and losing connection between requests is not a problem, then the client can send multiple requests parallel or series using a simple loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could use matrix parameters for the delete.  Given that the parameters are resource IDs you could use unnamed parameters, so for example a `DELETE` to `https://host.com/messages/1;2;3` would remove messages with IDs 1, 2 and 3.